# Making xml query in Python script

Tags: python, xml, search, scripting, contains

```
module_rm = "resource-mgr"
def get_data_name(self, path):
    dataClass = "logicalRouterInterface"
    dataProp = "dn"
    msg = """<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <configResolveClass cookie="""+ self.authenticate()+ """ inHierarchical="false" classId=""" + "\"" + dataClass + "\"" + """>
    <inFilter>
            <eq class=""" + "\"" + dataClass + "\"" + """
            property=""" + "\"" + dataProp + "\"" + """
            value=""" + "\"" + path + "\"" + """
        />
    </inFilter>
    </configResolveClass>"""
    xml_response = self.send_xml(msg, module_rm)

    root = ET.fromstring( xml_response )
    dataint = root.findall("./outConfigs/" + dataClass)
    print "Number of matching datainterface ", len(dataint)
```

The variable path contains value "org-root/org-tcs/org-edgerouter-csr1" but the dataClass i.e  "logicalRouterInterface", dataProp i.e. "dn" exact value is "org-root/org-tcs/org-edgerouter-csr1/router-intf-data2" but i dont know the exact value i know only the part of value.
This query returns no matching interface as it needs exact value. Pls help to modify this so that it search based on this partial value.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your input XML (`msg`) is missing the quote for `cookie=`. It might work after fixing it:

```
    <configResolveClass cookie=\""""+ self.authenticate()+ """\" inHierarchical="false" classId=""" + "\"" + dataClass + "\"" + """>
```

Comment: The code is working. But in value attribute i am passing partial string "org-root/org-tcs/org-edgerouter-csr1" but its complete value is "org-root/org-tcs/org-edgerouter-csr1/router-intf-data2". So, it return 0 match. If i pass complete value then it return right. But I dont know complete value.

Comment: What you have is application specific, which I have no idea what it is to help. I am sorry.